# PHP imap_open(): Couldn't open stream to gmail

Tags: php, email, gmail, gmail-imap, php-imap

I'm getting this messages when I tried to use [php-imap](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php) to retrieve emails from server using IMAP protocol. I started with gmail accounts. But when I tried to connect using [imap_open()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-open.php) I get the following messages:

`Warning: imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {imap.gmail.com/imap/ssl:993}INBOX in \path\to\file\imap.php on line 6`

or

`Warning: imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {imap.gmail.com/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert:993}INBOX in \path\to\file\imap.php on line 6`

depending if I use or not novalidate-cert

I found some related question, but not the solution

[imap_open(): Couldn't open stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31407571/imap-open-couldnt-open-stream)

[Getting Error like imap_open(): Couldn't open stream in server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19109686/getting-error-like-imap-open-couldnt-open-stream-in-server)

[Connecting to Gmail IMAP PHP "Couldn't open stream"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11772240/connecting-to-gmail-imap-php-couldnt-open-stream)

Is it possible connect to email using the imap php extension?
If, Yes. How can I solved this message?

If, No. Which alternative for received email using PHP could be possible?

Comment: Are you sure your host let's you connect to port 993?

Comment: It's gmail imap port.

Comment: Yes, I know that.  Are you sure *your* host does not have it firewalled?  Many web hosts do.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. There isn't firewall. I can connect to my company email that is in remote server.

Answer (score 2):

Try imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl. Port number comes after the domain name and befor the URI path.